# pause executed thread and then re-use same thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I m using winform, vs2012
process flow: user selects a file, I do some work on that file, then user selects another file, I do some work on another file

What I want is:  (it does not matters if it can be done using thread, backgroundworker or any other thing)
display a "**processing form with animated picturebox**" while doing some work with first file
display a "**processing form with animated picturebox**" while doing some work with second file
after work done, **close the "processing" form (started with thread)**

Here user will select a file using openfiledialog

```
Private Sub btn_first_file_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_first_file.Click
        If (some logic)
             'do the process on file (time consuming code)
             'open "processing" form with new thread (with only animated picturebox)
             'when task done, close/hide the "processing" form
        End If  

Private Sub btn_second_file_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_second_file.Click
        If (some logic)
             'do the process on file (time consuming code)
             'open "processing" form with new thread (with only animated picturebox)
             'when task done, close the "processing" form
        End If           
    End Sub
```

what I have tried:
executed above logic, but I use thread.abort after work done, later I found that it's not good to use abort function.
case-1: if I abort the thread
if user go back and select another file (using openfiledialog) then in the above code block thread will not restart (and processing form will not open)
case-2: if I don't abort the thread
if the user go back 5 time then "processing form" opens five time (with thread's 5 instance)

I tried the same logic with backgroundworker, but the issue is **gif can not load properly on picturebox** (picturebox is on processing form- started with new thread)
and how to close processing form which was opened with thread, because if I abort the thread, "processing" form is not closing.

Comment: Why not jsut ask the user to pick two files at the start of the process, do all the work in a BackgroundWorker, and regularly ProgressChanged to provide some meaningful alteration to the animation in the picturebox?

Comment: Be careful mixing windows controls with threading; a control can only be reliably accessed by the same thread that created it. If you're just blindly updating an animation, rather than have the animation be some sort of custom progress bar, just use a timer to update the anim, and do the work async so you don't block the UI thread (and have only one UI thread)

Comment: (1) only after selection of the first file further process can continue (2) first file is only image file and second file is data file like txt, img, video, rar etc and second file can be of only 1-2 mb or 200-300 mb (3) I m not updating progress, what I m trying is just display picturebox with animated gif on another winform while some time consuming code is executing on UI thread.

Comment: I'm not sure it answers why user can't select both files at the start but ok, it's not so important.. The biggest problem with your approach is *while some time consuming code is executing on UI thread* - the Windows Forms cardinal sin

Comment: time consuming code is creating rar file of the user selected file (which can be upto gb), and I can't understand "the Windows Forms cardinal sin"

Comment: *while some time consuming code is executing on UI thread* - never execute "some time consuming code on the UI thread"

Comment: Tell us more about what these two processes are doing

Comment: If you want to support overlapping operations (start file 1 - start file 2 - finish file 1 - finish file 2) then you'll probably need to keep some sort of in-progress counter; with multiple threads, accessing the counter (whether to read or to update) will require using the appropriate thread-safe data access tools (locks and/or interlocked operations).

Comment: You should find [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?869567) useful.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, it's very very useful to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use a BackgroundWorker or Task Async Pattern for what you're doing;

- Have your "the process is ongoing" indicator form be a new form that you show just like any other - it contains an active timer that ticks and animates something, and the timer runs on form show and stops on hide
- Keep an instance of this form  in a class level variable in the main class that does the long process. Show this form (not as a dialog) at the start of the process (in the button click handler)
- Run the process in a backgroundworker's dowork event, and make the runworkercompleted event hide the animation form, OR make your long process TAP (async) compatible and await it, then close the form when the waiting is done

Comment: Thanks Sir, I was trying to same as you described here (but my logic was little bit foggy), but your explanation made my day, really very helpful, thanks again.